# Bytes vs codepoints in ruby

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between ruby string functions:- codepoints and bytes

```
'abcd'.bytes
=> [97, 98, 99, 100]

'abcd'.codepoints
=> [97, 98, 99, 100]
```

Comment: try unicode strings

Comment: Adding on to @SergioTulentsev's comment `"\u2713".bytes = [226, 156, 147]` whereas `"\u2713".codepoints = [10003]`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev so, codepoints are for the unicode strings. Then why Chinese characters are returning different results

Comment: @Vivakkumar: example?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  I think you have given the answer for the chinese character?                                                                                                     s = '日本語'
s.bytes # => [230, 151, 165, 230, 156, 172, 232, 170, 158]
s.codepoints # => [26085, 26412, 35486]

Comment: Yes, have you read the answer? If you need to break string into characters, use either `chars` or `codepoints` (whatever is appropriate to your use case). Use `bytes` only when you treat string as an opaque binary blob, not text.

Comment: Great ASCII/UTF-8 introduction: [Characters, Symbols and the Unicode Miracle - Computerphile](https://youtu.be/MijmeoH9LT4)

Comment: @Stefan: yes, I LOVE that video! It was the one that made unicode click in my head.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`bytes` returns individual bytes, regardless of char size, whereas `codepoints` returns unicode codepoints.

```
s = '日本語'
s.bytes # => [230, 151, 165, 230, 156, 172, 232, 170, 158]
s.codepoints # => [26085, 26412, 35486]
s.chars # => ["日", "本", "語"]
```

I see where your confusion arises from. Ruby uses utf-8 encoding by default now and utf-8 was specifically designed so that its first codepoints (0-127) are **exactly** the same as in ASCII encoding. ASCII is an encoding with one-byte chars, so in examples in your question methods `bytes` and `codepoints` return the same values, *coincindentally*.

So, if you need to break string into characters, use either `chars` or `codepoints` (whichever is appropriate for your use case). Use `bytes` only when you treat string as an opaque binary blob, not text.

---

Actually, `chars` (suggested above) might not be accurate enough, since unicode has notion of combining characters and modifier letters. If you care about this, you need to use so-called "grapheme clusters". Here's an example (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54457724/125816):

[image: glyph]

```
s = "a\u0308\u0303\u0323\u032d"
s.bytes # => [97, 204, 136, 204, 131, 204, 163, 204, 173]
s.codepoints # => [97, 776, 771, 803, 813]
s.chars # => ["a", "̈", "̃", "̣", "̭"]
s.grapheme_clusters # => ["ạ̭̈̃"] # rendering of this glyph is kinda broken, which illustrates the point that unicode is hard
```

Comment: Also to verify that the bytes are corresponding you can do `s.bytes.pack('c*').force_encoding('UTF-8') == s` which should be true.

Comment: @sergio Tulentsev so can you tell me then why we are using codepoints

Comment: @Vivakkumar: "why we are using codepoints" - who are we and where are we using them? I don't understand the question, I'm afraid. Haven't you seen the updated answer?

Comment: @serigio Tulentsev can you please tell me a scenario

Comment: @Vivakkumar: it's in the answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you